# spring boot backend blocks the front end application because of CORS policy

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors

I am using Spring boot and angular. I have used the cross origin annotation mentioning my localhost port of angular but despite that I am getting the following error

[image]

My Spring boot codes are following

My Model class

public class User {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String userName;
private String password;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String phoneNumber;
private boolean enabled = true;
private String profile;}
```

The controller class is following

```
package com.exam.portal.controller;

import com.exam.portal.entity.Role;
import com.exam.portal.entity.User;
import com.exam.portal.entity.UserRole;
import com.exam.portal.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/")
    public User createUser(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {

        Set<UserRole>roles = new HashSet<>();
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setRoleId(44L);
        role.setRoleName("NORMAL");

        UserRole userRole = new UserRole();
        userRole.setUser(user);
        userRole.setRole(role);
        roles.add(userRole);
        return userService.createUser(user,roles);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{username}")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable("username")String userName){
    return userService.getUserByUserName(userName);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable("id")Long id){
         userService.deleteUser(id);
    }
}
```

Angular code of sevice

```
constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }
  public addUser(user:any){
    console.log("user data is ",user);
    return this.http.post(`${baseURL}/user/`,user);
    
  }
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the protocol in your `baseURL`.

Comment: thanks! I seem to have missed it.It worked .

Comment: use `http:// ` before `baseURL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your variable `baseURL` is missing the **http://** before **localhost:8088**.